# Apache RewriteRule to simulate directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

is there a way to tell Apache to simulate a directory in the URL ?

Here is what I'm trying to do... I currently have an URL like http://photo.mydomain.com/pics/17/120417/1.jpg and I would like to be able to reach the same content with an URL like http ://photo.mydomain.com/pics/51/17/120417/1.jpg .

Is that possible ? If yes, a little of bit would be much appreciated :-)

Thanks !

Comment: URL paths are not file system paths. And thus there are no directories in URL paths, only segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^pics/\d{2}/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)$ pics/$1
```

---

**Edit**    
Since you’re using this rule in the `<VirtualHost>` section and not in a .htaccess file, you need to use the full path with path prefix in the pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^/pics/\d{2}/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)$ pics/$1
```

Only in .htaccess files you need to remove them:

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically *removed* for the pattern matching and automatically *added* after the substitution has been done.

Comment: Thanks, but the rule doesn't seems to work and I'm getting a 404. I've enable rewrites logging and I'm seeing that the rules is properly interpreted.

Comment: @Sylvain V: Do you use any other rules that might get in conflict with this one?

Comment: @Sylvain V: And where do you use this rule? Did you try other rules to verify that mod_rewrite is enabled and working?

Comment: yes, in another vhost I've a website running which is using rewrites and that works properly

Comment: @Sylvain V: Ok, in that case you need to prepend `/` to the pattern. I thought you wanted to use it in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pics/\d{2}/(.+)$ pics/$1
```

"\d{2}" would be "51" and "(.+)" means one or more symbols

Comment: Thanks, but the rule doesn't seems to work and I'm getting a 404. I've enable rewrites logging and I'm seeing that the rules is properly interpreted.

Comment: ok, rewrite has been changed to RewriteRule ^pics/\d{2}/(.+)$ pics/$1 [R] and the returned URL doesn't changed, if I add the /51/ or not, and I'm getting a 404 with /51/